# Remote file sync using WCF and Microsoft Sync File

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm a newbie in MSF. I need to implement a project which can synchronize files on difference computers. I searched and found a sample project, here is the link: [Sync file using WCF and WSF](http://www.8bit.rs/blog/2010-04-an-update-to-remote-file-sync-using-wcf-and-msf/)

But, this is an incomplete project and only one direction synchronization. Can you help me how we can synchronize file for bi-direction. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have u got the answer

Comment: yes, I do it by myself :V

Comment: please add the answer @hoangnguyen